# How to dispose NimaAnimations in Flutter

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, android-animation

I am using a Nima Aimation in one of my Dart files. However, I am unable to dispose it once it is completed. NimaAnimation has an abstract class for NimaController but unfortunately it does not have any dispose function to stop it.

The problem that I am facing because of this are the performance issues. I even tried using the performance overlay to observe the memory usage and I did notice that the animation is not disposed off and it continues rendering in the backend even when I have navigated to a new Screen. The code that I have written for this is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:maui/screens/tab_home.dart';
import 'package:nima/nima_actor.dart';

class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new WelcomeScreenState();
}

class WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen> {
  bool delayed;
  var animatecontrol = null;
  NimaController nimaController;
 NimaActor nima ;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
       nima = new NimaActor(
      "assets/quack",
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      animation: 'welcome with hello',
      mixSeconds: 0.2,

    );
    new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 6200), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/tab');
      setState(() {
     nima.controller;
        delayed = true;
      });
    });
  }

  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MediaQueryData media = MediaQuery.of(context);

    var size = media.size;


    // TODO: implement build
    return (delayed == true)
        ? new TabHome()
        : new Scaffold(
            body: new Container(
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                ),
                child: new Stack(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: size.height > size.width ? 1.5 : 3.8,
                              child: nima,
                            ),
                          ])
                    ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nima Animator has attributes paused and completed. These can help in controlling the animation state. for details refer to this link(example):

https://github.com/2d-inc/Nima-Flutter/blob/master/example/hop/lib/main.dart